# Dynamic hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Here is an example of my mapping file:

```
<!-- ============================ -->
<!-- Table TABLE1 -->
<!-- ============================ -->
<class table="TABLE1"
    name="com.myCompany.Entity1" lazy="false" schema="SCHEMA1">
    <!-- Attributs -->
    <id column="ID" name="id" type="string" />
    <property column="ACTION_TYPE" name="actionType"
        type="com.myCompany.ActionEnumType" not-null="true" />
    <property column="PRIORITY" name="priority"
        type="com.myCompany.PriorityEnumType" not-null="true" />
    <property column="DATE_MAJ" name="dateMaj" />
</class>
<!-- ============================ -->
<!-- Table TABLE2 -->
<!-- ============================ -->
<class table="TABLE2"
    name="com.myCompany.Entity2"
    lazy="false"  schema="SCHEMA2">
    <!-- Attributs -->
    <id column="ID" name="id" type="string" />
    <property column="ACTION_TYPE" name="actionType"
        type="com.myCompany.ActionEnumType" not-null="true" />
    <property column="PRIORITY" name="priority"
        type="com.myCompany.PriorityEnumType" not-null="true" />
    <property column="DATE_MAJ" name="dateMaj" />
</class>
<!-- ============================ -->
<!-- Table TABLE3 -->
<!-- ============================ -->
<class table="TABLE3"
    name="com.myCompany.Entity3"
    lazy="false"  schema="SCHEMA3">
    <!-- Attributs -->
    <id column="ID" name="id" type="string" />
    <property column="ACTION_TYPE" name="actionType"
        type="com.myCompany.ActionEnumType" not-null="true" />
    <property column="PRIORITY" name="priority"
        type="com.myCompany.PriorityEnumType" not-null="true" />
    <property column="DATE_MAJ" name="dateMaj" />
</class>
```

The goal, is to put all the data to be configurable in one external file.
The purpose is to define the schema name dynamically because it depends on the deployment environment.
 Unfortunetely, we can't use in our project neither Maven nor Ant.
How or where can i set the different schemas name to resolve this issue?

Thx in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for such thing, so using a tool like Maven or Ant for dynamically setting this value based on a properties file is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this in Hibernate. However we use Ant to achieve this with help of environment specific property files.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supports defining a default catalog for unqualified table names in the configuration files (either in `hibernate.cfg.xml` or in `hibernate.properties`) using the `hibernate.default_schema` property. From the documentation:

> ### [3.4. Optional configuration properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)
>
> ...
>
> hibernate.default_schema:      Qualify unqualified table names with the given schema/tablespace in generated SQL. **e.g.** SCHEMA_NAME

Depending on the complexity of your use case, this might help (or not). If it doesn't, I'm afraid you'll have to use some kind of filtering approach (Ant also offers filtering) - or to patch Hibernate.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but in my case i will have to use classes mapped to tables existing in 5 different shcemas in the same oracle instance.

Comment: @ilikejava: This won't help in that case.